# Entity Framework Context Factory And Cyclic References

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, refactoring, unity-container

I try to create a factory for entity framework contexts.

#### 1. Goal

In a **PersonDataService** (in the *assembly DataService*) I want to have the following method:

```
public void GetPerson(int id)
{
    using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create<IPersonContext>())
    {
         var personRepository = this.repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);
         return personRepository.Get(id);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Given

In our project, there is an assembly called *DependencyInjection* where we setup all of our unity config so this assembly has references to alot of projects including the assembly *DataAccess* where entity framework is.

The ContextFactory should look something like this:

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : IDbContext
    {
        return UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

The assembly *DependencyInjection* also has a reference of the assembly *DataService*.

#### 3. Problem

> DataService <-- DependencyInjection
>       ^                            ^
>       |                             |
> DataAccess --------------

- If I place the `ContextFactory` in the assembly *DependencyInjection* (because I need Unity) I can't use it in the *DataService*.
- If I place the `ContextFactory` in the assembly *DataAccess*, I can't use Unity in the factory

What is the best way to resolve this cyclic reference problem?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** The reason I want to introduce the `ContextFactory` is, that I want to use an InMemoryContext in my acceptance test and to be able to setup a fake of the `ContextFactory` to return this InMemoryContext when a call to `Create<T>` happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think, problem is in decision to have one assembly for container configuration. I don't see a lot of benefits.

As a solution, I can advice you to use following project structure:

1. Create an assembly with public interfaces
2. Create an assembly with internal implementations of interfaces
3. Confugure Unity-container in assembly 2
4. Expose Unity-container configuration with UnityContainerExtension class

---

### Example

Assemply 1:

```
public interface ISecurityService
{
    SignInStatus SignIn(string email, string password, bool isPersistent);
    void SignOut();
}
```

Assembly 2:

```
internal sealed class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User, long> _signInManager;
    public SecurityService(SignInManager<User, long> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _signInManager.UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(_signInManager.UserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };
    }

    public SignInStatus SignIn(string email, string password, bool isPersistent)
    {
        var status = _signInManager.PasswordSignIn(email, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout: false);
        return status;
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        _signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
    }
}

public sealed class ApplicationExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
        Container.RegisterType<IPrincipal>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.User));
        Container.RegisterType<ISecurityService, SecurityService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

Assembly 3:

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddExtension(new ApplicationExtension());
        //use container
    }
}
```

Advantages:

1. Your interfaces are public and separated from implementation
2. Implementation is internal and can be used only via interface
3. You expose configured container from assembly